# convert float to string with four numeric value

Tags: c#, string, double

I have a float value like below,

```
20.0
```

I want to convert 20.0 value to string like below,

```
20.0000
```

**Result must be,**

```
if float 20.0 than string must be 20.0000

if float 10.0 than string must be 10.0000
```

**How can i convert float value(20.0) to string value(20.0000) ?**

Any help will be appreciated. Code I have now:

```
//worksheet.Cells[j, 7].Value = sonuc1.Unit.ToString() != "" ? (CellValue)sonuc1.Unit : ""; var deneme1 = Convert.ToDecimal(sonuc1.Unit); 
var deneme2 = Convert.ToDouble(sonuc1.Unit); 
var deneme3 = double.Parse("0.01000"); 
var deneme = sonuc1.Unit; 
worksheet.Cells[j, 7].Value = sonuc1.Unit.ToString() != "" ? (CellValue)sonuc1.Unit : "";
```

Comment: i hope you can help because you are very serios.

           //worksheet.Cells[j, 7].Value = sonuc1.Unit.ToString() != "" ? (CellValue)sonuc1.Unit : "";

                    var deneme1 = Convert.ToDecimal(sonuc1.Unit);
                    var deneme2 = Convert.ToDouble(sonuc1.Unit);


                    var deneme3 = double.Parse("0.01000");
                    var deneme = sonuc1.Unit;

                    worksheet.Cells[j, 7].Value = sonuc1.Unit.ToString() != "" ? (CellValue)sonuc1.Unit : "";

Comment: `float f = 10.0f; f.ToString("00.0000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) // 10.000`

Comment: `10f.ToString("F4", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: And next time, please do some research first. You can find tons of informations in Google about _float to string_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need simply **enforce** result string to show more zeroes if need.

```
var a = 20.0f; 
a.ToString("00.0000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
//2 digits before and 4 digits after (.)
```

Pay attention on fact that in your case the value *may* not be *exactly* `20.0`, but something like `20.0012`. In these cases you need to first convert it to exact `20.0`, after format it to string.

Comment: Personally.. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252531/447156

Comment: @SonerGönül: this does not look like a bad question to me. OP is, probably, lost in neat floating point treatment (conversions to and from).